# Change partition key of humongous table

Tags: postgresql

Created new table with similar index's and new range partition key ensuring old table is intact for backup. Note old table has different partition key.

Now the issue is slowness due to constraints and indexes in new table while inserting table of size 3 billion rows.

Couldn't find example similar to COPY to move data from other table.
Is there a efficient standard way?